# Java "Could not find the main class emeraldrandomizer.EmeraldRandomizerApp. Program will exit."

Tags: java, class, windows-7

I can't seem to get this program to work, and I am at a loss for why.

When I type java in to "run" (Using windows 7), I get the message

```
   "Windows could not find Java".
```

I also have installed java and re-installed it to no avail. I have a feeling the directory is messed up (probably because I butchered it when I changed the boot drive to my SSD, and used my old hard drive as an internal storage drive).

Comment: what happens when you open a cmd and type `java -version`? And your title differs from your question, could you clarify what the problem is? is it Could not find the main class or Could not find java?

Answer (score 0):

your windows PATH for java is probably the problem.

when you type in java in to the run screen...windows locates the version of java defined by the path.

1) try typing java -version

if that doesn't work windows can't find the java installation.

2) try finding the java exciutable where you install java and trying running that directly

if that works its a path problem